# Google ADB driver file doesn't contain a driver for my device

Tags: android, adb

I've recently changed my PC and I'm stuck on installing ADB drivers. I've searched for tutorials and followed each step but after the selection of the win_usb.inf file, I got this error:

> The specified location does not contain a compatible software driver for your device. If the location contains a driver, make sure it is designed to work with the Windows x64 Edition operating system.

So, I've decided to modify the .inf file manually, by reading other tutorials. After that, I could install the "ADB Composite Interface" driver but ADB still doesn't see my device.

What should I do?

Thank you in advance.

Edit: the device is LG Leon 3G and the PC has a 64 bit Intel processor with Windows 10 home edition

Comment: It might help to name the device in case somebody else has had the same problem.

Comment: are you sure your device connects as a media device when you connect it through usb?

Comment: Yes, I connect it using MTP and the computer sees the phone as a Mobile Device but ADB doesn't

Comment: is USB Debugging enabled?

Comment: Yes, it's enabled on the device

Comment: Try to look for general Mediatek usb drivers, they should be compatible.

Comment: I'll try this also because the LG drivers solved nothing

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Download this tool from [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0bfQe5C01sNSjlsQlE5VVZTcm8) it helped me many times when i was stuck with drivers.

You just need to open this tool & fetch your device & install adb drivers

[image: Refer this screen]

Comment: Try rebooting you phone, if still nothing something is wrong with your device / PC.

Comment: I can already say that is my PC fault because that message didn't appear on my old asus but I don't know how to fix it

Comment: I could finally solve the issue by using PTP mode instead of MTP and by installing drivers through ADB Driver Installer 2.0

Comment: First, the Google Drive link you provided just gives a "request access" page. Secondly, do not use links in posts as they may become broken in the future.